# typescript generics interface, method parameter and method return type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function

```
function getCollection<T>(collectionType: T): Collection<T> {
  return new Collection<T>()
}
```

and in `Collection` class I have this

```
export class Collection<T> {
  public add (item: T) {
    // .. logic
  }
}
```

I have a user interface defined like this

```
export interface IStudent {

}
```

and when I attempt to do

```
getCollection(IStudent).add({});
```

There is an error

> TS2693: 'IStudent' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

How do I make it accept generic type and returned strictly typed Collection?

Comment: You can’t pass a type like that, you can either constrain the function with <IStudent> or pass a variable that has the shape of IStudent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic type is a *type* parameter, not a function parameter. You define

```
function getCollection<T>(): Collection<T> {
  return new Collection<T>()
}
```

(notice `collectionType` was an unused parameter anyway) and then call it as

```
getCollection<IStudent>().add({});
```

Comment: thank you. how do I access the type parameter in function body to retrieve the type name?

Comment: @user3833308 You cannot. Types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi. Do you know how reliable annotations/decorators are? (ie - new library should rely on those or still consider them "experimental"?

Comment: Afaik, typescript decorators are not up to date with the latest draft, and any transpilers that would be are definitely experimental. I doubt they'll stop working at some point though